# Trailing comma at the end of the last object field JS

Tags: javascript, coding-style, conventions

Is there a hidden meaning in a case where the last object field is followed by a trailing comma? For example, webstorm by default formats code according to the first case. But for me it seems a little messy, for example, in webpack config files where there is an object with a lot of fields.

```
const object = {
  field: '123',
};

const object = {
  field: '123'
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about it. A trailing comma is optional, but has no bearing on the code itself. It is just a style thing.

Some people prefer to have the trailing comma because then if you add a new row, in your Git commits, the diff will only affect the new line added. Without the trailing comma, adding a new row will show two lines changing.

Beyond that, there really isn't much of a difference.

Comment: I remember the fad a few years ago where developers were putting commas at the _beginning_ of the new line to solve that problem, and not make it messy. Of course, it made their code look _insane_.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that as well. It works... but it also drives me crazy. =p It's good though in languages where you can't have a trailing comma.